# "asked" vs. "was asked" in a title

Tags: titles, passive-voice

I just encountered this news heading: "All-Female Flight Test Crew Asked How They Will Cope Without Make-Up Or Men In Space"

This confused me, because I understood from the heading that the "crew asked". But according to the article, it was actually reporters in a press conference that asked the crew. Shouldn't the heading be "Crew Was Asked" accordingly?

Comment: Explanation of Newspaper Headlines for English Learners
esl.about.com›od…a/newsheadlines.htm
You can find some information here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the verb [***ask***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ask) is used to mean:

> Say something in order to obtain an answer or some information.

It is (usually) a transitive verb that ***requires an object***.

> "All-Female Flight Test Crew Asked How They Will Cope Without Make-Up
>   Or Men In Space"

In the above example, if the how-clause were used as an object of "asked", "*will*" should be changed to "*would*" as the main verb of the sentence "asked" is "past tense".

Therefore, the how-clause is not the object of the verb "ask" and we can assume that "were" is omitted between "crew" and "asked".

In a headline, articles and the verb "be" are often omitted to ***save space (for brevity)*** because it is not that difficult to catch what it means without them.

Comment: Should've said this in the original message, but I accepted this, because it didn't only point out the tendency to omit "be" in news headlines, but also explained that there is an actual difference between the meanings, i.e. the sentence is NOT ambivalent, although it ALMOST is. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Some publications prefer not to include 'to be' verbs in headlines—but as you observe with regard to this example, a literal reading of the wording can produce an unintended (and very different) meaning in some cases.

Here, a more accurate headline would have been "Reporters Trivialize All-Female Space Mission With Queries About Make-up, Lack of Men." But for some reason, journalists hate to make themselves the focus of attention in a headline, even when the accompanying story is about little more than their own lame behavior.

Comment: I agree.  What's up with reporters being such dolts lately?